# multi-person event registration

Tags: civievent, registration, price-sets

I am trying to make a very complex event price matrix as simple as possible for the people registering.

1. Multi-person registration is on - many families attend
2. There are Adult, child and young child (free) price brackets
3. There are SIX accommodation options (including no accommodation)
   with varying availability. Some are "per bed" but others (powered
   tent sites) would be by booking (as one tent could be 1 - 8 people,
   hence it's the number of sites which limits, not the participants).
4. Then there's a member discount (fortunately a constant amount)
5. and a self-catering discount (will be done by a coupon code).
6. and of course earlybird, standard and late pricing bands - which
   Civi handles with aplomb.
7. There's a one-extra night option (which should be in the same
   accommodation as for the event).
8. There's a family discount for 2A+2C

It's easy enough to make a whole bunch of price sets, but the participant limits (e.g. only 50 small room beds available) won't span across adult/child price fields, so availability will have to be carefully monitored by the event team and options disabled manually as they fill up.

The biggest simplifiction I'd like to achieve is that a group of people registering together want the same accommodation option (if they don't, they can register separately!), so I'd like them to only have to choose the accommodation option once, not for each person and not for the extra night option.

Can anyone see a way to approach this?